# Can i Still Burn DVD-R even if im using SATA USB 2.0 for external disc drive

Tags: sata, dvd, burning

Ok I removed the disc drive of my laptop because its no use anymore to me and good thing the disc drive still works the last time i use it, it has Ability to burn anytype of dvd but im worried about it may not burn with sata usb 2.0 because i heard that external disc drive with usb 2.0 can only burn cd-r but not dvd-r while my disc drive had a capability of burning anything as a said,so can i still burn blank dvd's even using usb 2.0 only? plus 3.0 wasn't available in my country so 2.0 was the only choice.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: From the answer below: *I wonder if you are confusing DVD and Bluray?* I think this is crux of the question.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the specific USB-to-SATA bridge you use. Many will allow you to use burn optical media, but some won't.

You have to test the ones you have.

Exact USB version is irrelevant. USB 2.0 has more bandwidth than those recordable media, so it is enough to even burn them at fastest speed. What should concern you is power usage, check that your drive has enough power to operate reliably.

Comment: Ok seems reasonable answer thanks

Answer (score 1):

You were informed wrong. USB DVD burners were a thing (still are for the very few people who care).  I dont believe you will find many USB CD/DVD drives that cant burn DVD's - this technology came into its own about the same time as ultrabooks - what which time DVDs were bulk standard.

I wonder if you are confusing DVD and Bluray?